# Можно ли создать функцию в C#, которая принимает переменное количество массивов?

Tags: c#

Нужно создать функцию, которая принимает различное количество массивов.Массивы считываются с текстового файла(то есть 1 файл - 1 массив) , далее их объединяем и на выходе получается один массив. Можно ли так сделать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6):

Принимает массив массивов и склеивает их:

```
public static T[] CombineArrays<T>(T [][] arrays)
{
    return arrays.SelectMany(arr => arr).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Уточнение: поскольку автор просил *переменное* количество массивов, наверное стоит перед параметром написать ключевое слово `params`

Comment: @PavelMayorov а возможно и не стоит. этот метод принимает вполне переменное число массивов. скорее всего стандартный метод обучения с "есть статически массивы, а есть - с *переменным* количеством значений" сработал

Answer (score 3):

Передавайте массив массивов.
Но, дабы не писать очередной велосипед, посмотрите на [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx).